# How exclude all test jars* from mvn dependency:tree

Tags: maven, jar, dependency-tree

is there any way to exclude dependencies used during test goal?
For example I would like to avoid having all `*:tests` jar printed by `mvn dependency:tree`.

```
[INFO] Building test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] com.test.test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.specs2:specs2-core_2.13:jar:4.8.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.specs2:specs2-matcher_2.13:jar:4.8.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.specs2:specs2-common_2.13:jar:4.8.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.specs2:specs2-fp_2.13:jar:4.8.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.scala-sbt:test-interface:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] +- org.scalatest:scalatest_2.13:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.scalactic:scalactic_2.13:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.13.1:test
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile
```

Many jars are used during the compile phase while others during test phase.
I was looking to the:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dexcludes=org.apache.maven*
```

so I was wondering if it is possible to directly exclude all `*tests` via the command line.

Comment: Have you tried to use `mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=compile`?

Comment: @khmarbaise tks, it works

Comment: If this was your fix, I suggest that @khmarbaise adds it as an answer and for you to accept.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add the `scope` like this:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=compile
```

Comment: I have not tried it but following the documentation (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) it does not work ("currently").

Comment: Maybe the documentation is outdated or fails to specify the scenarios it fails? It worked for my usecase with -Dscope=compile. I see the provided and compile scope and test is filtered. Maybe it's a bug because only compile should have been shown?

Comment: If you think there is a bug open an issue https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/issue-management.html

Comment: This worked well for me with Maven 3.8.5.  To include both runtime and compile dependencies, I used `mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=runtime`.